# adding content in the middle of smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

how can I modify a smarty variable on tpl file and add some data after certain position without using php? is it possible?

suppose,

```
$var="this is test content for a variable";
```

and i want to add "EXTRA DATA " after 8th character position so that the final output will be "this is EXTRA DATA test content for a variable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
{$var|substr:0:8}EXTRA DATA {$var|substr:8}
```

May I ask why you're not wanting to do this in PHP? It's more suited there, this is not the job that a template should be doing.

Comment: Arguably, all display/layout modification belongs in the view/template. It does seem a bit odd, though. I try to keep templates as simple as possible, and the two approaches can conflict with each other.

Comment: I'd agree most of the time, for instance a `{$var|truncate:30}...`, but to actually want to modify the data that comes out is weird and wrong (in my opinion!).

Comment: Indeed :) Actually, truncation is a good example as it gets ugly in templates to _only_ display the "`...`" when a truncation was actually performed... even though semantically _all_ of that logic belongs in the view.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can truncate the sentencen use http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl

then add your extra word as smarty varible

Comment: The OP is not asking for truncation.